# Null pointer exception on getting value from onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() - Android

Tags: android

I am developing an application which plays 2 audio files simultaneously with different Mediaplayer instance. To retain the state of mediaplayer on screen rotation implemented the method

```
  public  Object  onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() 
             {
                    HashMap<String,Object> player = new HashMap<String,Object>();
                    MediaPlayer instance = mp;
                    mp = null;
                    MediaPlayer instance1 = mp1;
                    mp1 = null;
                    player.put("mp", instance);
                    player.put("mp1", instance1);
                     return player;

              }
```

In onCreate(),

```
    HashMap<String, Object> playerhandle = (HashMap<String, Object>)getLastNonConfigurationInstance();            
                  mp = (MediaPlayer)playerhandle.get("mp");
                      if (mp == null) 
                      {
                         mp = new MediaPlayer();
                       }
                      mp1 = (MediaPlayer)playerhandle.get("mp1");
                      if (mp1 == null) 
                      {
                        mp1 = new MediaPlayer();
                      }
```

Showing NullPointerException in logcat........

Answer (score 0):

You never check if `playerhandle` is `null`